# why php5 can find my class, but php7 can't?

Tags: laravel, namespaces, php-7, classnotfound

I have an application based on Laravel 5.2 which is using php 5.6 and I decided that it would be great to move my application to php7 (mostly for performance benefits). Everything seems to be working great, except php7 cannot find one specific class in my application.

The file is stored in app/Libraries/Main/Google/Auth/Auth.php file, it has a namespace Google and a class name GoogleAuth, so every time I want to use it, i just put - use Google/GoogleAuth; at the top of the file. In php5 this works great, but in php7 it cannot find the class. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I think remain one step, run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan clear-compiled`
 command. May be this command will solve this issue.

**UPDATE**

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database", 
        "app/Libraries/Main"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

After update your `composer.json` with above code, run below command:

```
//To clears all compiled files.
php artisan clear-compiled 

//To updates the autoload_psr4.php
composer dump-autoload

//updates the autoload_classmap.php
php artisan optimize
```

Comment: it just throws - Class 'Google\GoogleAuth' not found

Comment: Need "autoload" array from `composer.json`

Comment: "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Libraries/Main"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },

Comment: didn't work either and this killed the whole application, even the error message didn't show up. i have multiple classes in the libraries folder which are using namespaces not related to the file location, and they work only if the app/Libraries/Main is added to the classmap